# Verify throws java.security.InvalidKeyException: null

Tags: java, wildfly, bcrypt, elytron

I'm trying to write a service to handle user password hashing and verification. I'm using Wildfly Elytron libraries and using the service in the context of a quarkus web service. The issue I am coming across is that when I try to verify the password, the verify method throws a `java.security.InvalidKeyException`, with a `null` message. I've been using the library's [unit tests (javatips.net)](https://www.javatips.net/api/wildfly-security-master/wildfly-elytron-master/src/test/java/org/wildfly/security/password/impl/BCryptPasswordTest.java) to base my implementation on, and as far as I can tell I have things implemented correctly. As the exception literally has no message it's hard to know what is wrong, and googling doesn't yeild much. Any ideas?

```
    public PasswordService(
            PasswordValidator passwordValidator //my own password strength validator
    ){
        this.passwordValidator = passwordValidator;
        WildFlyElytronPasswordProvider provider = WildFlyElytronPasswordProvider.getInstance();

        try {
            this.passwordFactory = PasswordFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM, provider);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Somehow got an exception when setting up password factory. Error: ", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public String createPasswordHash(String password) throws PasswordValidationException {
        this.passwordValidator.validateAndSanitize(password);

        IteratedSaltedPasswordAlgorithmSpec iteratedAlgorithmSpec = new IteratedSaltedPasswordAlgorithmSpec(ITERATIONS, getSalt());
        EncryptablePasswordSpec encryptableSpec = new EncryptablePasswordSpec(password.toCharArray(), iteratedAlgorithmSpec);

        try {
            BCryptPassword original = (BCryptPassword) passwordFactory.generatePassword(encryptableSpec);
            return ModularCrypt.encodeAsString(original);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Somehow got an invalid key spec. This should not happen. Error: ", e);
            throw new WebServerException(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean passwordMatchesHash(String encodedPass, String pass) throws CorruptedKeyException{
        BCryptPassword original = null;
        try {
            original = (BCryptPassword) ModularCrypt.decode(encodedPass);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Somehow got an invalid key spec. This should not happen. Error: ", e);
            throw new WebServerException(e);
        }
        try {
            return passwordFactory.verify(original, pass.toCharArray()); // throws the invalid key exception
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Somehow got an invalid key. This probably shouldn't happen? Error: ", e);
            throw new WebServerException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hashing is not [tag:password-encryption].

Comment: Technically true thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The original link I posted for the unit tests were out of date, and thus was slightly wrong.

[Actual (up to date) tests](https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/1.x/password/impl/src/test/java/org/wildfly/security/password/impl/BCryptPasswordTest.java)

I was missing a wrapper for the decoding of the encoded hash:

`original = (BCryptPassword) passwordFactory.translate(ModularCrypt.decode(encodedPass));`